# How to make a perfect curve

Tags: modeling

Is there any way to create a perfect curve automatically without having to move the polygons manually?

[image: gun grip]

Comment: Do you know about curve objects? Also, what about proportional editing falloff?

Comment: Maybe not, I'm still learning

Comment: What do you mean by "a perfect curve"? Does proportional editing do what you need? In edit mode, press O to turn it on and experiment with it. Note that there are different settings for it which will give different results.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you could flat the surface then deform it with the Proportional Editing / Sphere Falloff type, or delete this surface, and completely recreate it from an circle arc.

Comment: I have no problem editing manually, but it would be interesting a tool to make symmetrical curves in large areas automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Relax function that comes with LoopTools add-on. The add-on comes with Blender so you just need to activate it in the User Preferences (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>). The function is then accessible from Specials menu (<kbd>w</kbd>), LoopTools submenu. It can be used with edge loops selected. Note all the options in the <kbd>t</kbd> panel that you can change.

[image]

Space function might also be useful:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using fewer polygons and letting the subsurf modifier work for you. For example, I tried replicating your shape with fewer edge loops:

[image]

Sparser geometry should make it easier to manipulate your subsurf'd mesh into curved shapes manually. Additionally, for a "perfect", arbitrary, non-destructive curve, I'd suggest using the [curve modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/deform/curve.html). This way you can guide your mesh with a [curve object](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/curves/structure.html#bezier-curves), which is ideal for describing a smooth curve with few points.

For perfectly repeating geometry, you can couple this with an array modifier for maximum non-destructivity:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yes, I certainly exaggerated in the subdivide.

Answer (score 0):

Or, to extrude to a specific curve:

- Draw your curve.. in its Data > Shape panel set its resolution to match the edge you're extruding from, bearing in mind resolution is per-segment.
- In Object Mode, <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> convert the curve to a mesh
- You may have to tweak the number of, and/or space the vertices - Loop Tools > Space will do that
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd> Join the meshes
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> Edge Menu > 'Bridge Edge Loops' (probably set to linear , with no profile influence)

[image]

Comment: I would have recommended bsurfaces, which theoretically should be ideal for this, but they've been [giving me jip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119160/bsurfaces-cant-set-cross-or-follow).