# Bsurfaces - can't set 'cross' or 'follow'

Tags: mesh, add-on

I'm having trouble using Bsurfaces (GPL, 1.5.1, shipped with Blender)

Sequence of events:

1. Create mesh object to contain surface
2. Create series of Bezier splines to be lofted, in a single curve object (The error is also occurring with Grease Pencil strokes attached to the mesh object)
3. Select curve, then mesh.
4. Put mesh into Edit Mode.
5. In the only available Bsurfaces panel, hit 'Add Surface'
6. The surface is created. So far, so good.
7. Another panel becomes available: 'Bsurfaces add surface'.
8. Any attempt to change the 'Cross' or 'Follow' fields in the new panel results in the following error:

   `Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\mesh_bsurfaces.py", line 3085, in execute bpy.data.objects[self.main_object.name].select = True
   ReferenceError: StructRNA of type Object has been removed`

This happens with whatever settings I try, (including 'Keep Strokes') in two builds of 2.79.

I've tried repairing the Blender installation, in case I've got the wrong script.. (where would I find one known to be good?)

Comment: I've just noticed this is essentially a duplicate of [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114445/bsurfaces-cannot-update-how-many-sections-i-want-to-retopo), but it does have a little more detail . I'll take it down and edit the previous post if that's the right thing to do

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug to me. there's [a tracker for bugs in official addons](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/2/), I'd suggest reporting there.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was kind of asking in the hope that others might succeed/fail in replicating this problem, in case it's _not_ a bug,  preparatory to making a proper report on the add-ons tracker. Is there a forum good for that? Go ahead and close, or I'll delete?

Comment: I can reproduce it here on 2.79 and Bsurfaces 1.5.1. No need to delete if you don't want to, this can serve as a pointer to the tracker for anyone else searching. (for some reason developer.blender.org doesn't show up in search results easily, at least for me..)

Comment: @gandalf3 As well as your link, it looks as if the 'Report Bug' button in User Prefs > Addons takes you to the right place. I'll make a report.